# Laravel 5.8, timeout session by Role

Tags: laravel, roles, session-timeout, laravel-middleware

i want to implement a system for tokens. I'm trying to set different inactive time values according to the role that the user has assigned. I tried using a middleware for this, but i wasn't capable of accesing the class or method that laravel uses for this. Any ideas?, thanks in advance :)

Comment: What session driver are you using?

Comment: I'm using "File"

Comment: You will need to extend the SessionManager on this method: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/874c4f6135a4c23d5c3040aa020b84aaaa41a3ca/src/Illuminate/Session/SessionManager.php#L57